# separate css file does not work on html file but put css in the same file as the html works

Tags: html, css

So I am reading a book called `<<teach yourself CSS and HTML in 24 hours>>`, when it comes to CSS the book asks readers to edit a style sheet in a separate .css file and put a link in the html file to link to the .css file. I did it but it does not work.

Then I watched a video clip on youtube that says I can simply add a `<style>` tag in my html file to make css work and i succeed.

The problem is I want to do this in the way that the book taught me because I think that will make my file easier to read for my own sake.

here is my code for `html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html>
  <head><title>Hello</title></head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css" />
  <body>
    <p>Hi my name is chris</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is my code for `mycss.css`:

```
p {
  color:green;
  font-family:arial;
}
```

however if i write it in this way, it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html>
  <head><title>Hello</title></head>
  <style type="text/css">
    p {color:green; font-family:arial;}
  </style>
  <body>
    <p>Hi my name is chris</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is mycss.css in the same directory as the html file calling it?  It will need to be in the same directory or you will need to provide the proper path in your <link... to find the file.

Comment: Hi beeker, thanks for your reply. yes, i did put them in the same directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this... Make sure the link to the style sheet is in the head section of the html document:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Hello</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hi my name is chris</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your external css link before `</head>` as below,

```
<head>
<title>Hello</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to include the stylesheet or the css file in the head section of the document.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css" />
</head>
```